# Javascript make variable a function that calls itself every time it's referenced

Tags: javascript, function

Hi I would like to know if it is possible to make a variable behave like this:

```
var someFlag  = true;
var someWidth = (()=>(someFlag) ? 16 : 12)();

console.log(someWidth) // 16

someFlag = false;

console.log(someWidth) // would be nice if it was 12
// right now it still prints 16
```

Is something like this possible? Also I know that someWidth could be a function, the idea is I have a lot of code I would need to refactor so I don't want to do someWidth();

Comment: That would only be possible if `someWidth` is a global variable (i.e. a property of the global object). Then you could define it as a getter. Not that this would be a great solution ;)

Comment: Interesting, that might involve more code than my refactoring lol oh well

Comment: just updated my answer to talk about with blocks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great way to describe object property is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```js
var someFlag  = true;
Object.defineProperty(window, 'someWidth', {

  get:()=>someFlag ? 16 : 12

})
console.log(someWidth) // 16

someFlag = false;
console.log(someWidth) // 12
```

I dont think its good idea to have such global variables.You can try to create your own object maybe?

Comment: nice, thanks for that, as a side note this project is in React Native, I might just do plain old function calls but this is interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, but it's not recommended.

If a name does not belong to a local variable, then it is looked for as the name of a property of the global object - which on the browser is `window`.  It is possible to use `defineProperty` on the `window` object to define a property with a getter function.

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'test', {
    get: function () { return 3; },
});
var x = test; // x = 3
```

However this is absolutely not recommended, because there is only one global context.  In the event that multiple separate JS modules define the same global variable, the definitions will clash and you will get crashes or some odd behavior.

Another thing you can do that's not recommended, is to use a `with` block, which would look like this:

```
var o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, 'test', {
    get: function () { return 3; },
});
with (o) {
    var x = test; // x = 3
}
```

The `with` keyword takes one object as a parameter.  Names inside the block are looked up first as properties of that object, *then* as local variables, *then* as properties of the global object.  This is not recommended either, because it requires that all names to be looked for first as properties of the object, which slows down code.

```
with (o) {
    var test = 4;
    var x = test; // x = 3
}
```

Also, Javascript has lexical scoping, not dynamic scoping, so you can't just wrap the top-level entry point in a `with` block, the whole program would have to be written inside a `with` block.

```
var f = function () {
    return test;
};
with (o) {
    var x = f(); // reference error: test is not defined
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I should've mentioned the project is in React Native so window object won't be an option. But great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would be a solution depending on what kind of refactoring you're looking at, but how about creating your own object with a modified getter/setter?

```js
var VariableWidth = {
    flag: true,
    get value() {
        return this.flag ? 16 : 12;
    },
    set setFlag(p_bool) {
      this.flag = p_bool;
    }
}

console.log(VariableWidth.value) // 16

VariableWidth.setFlag = false;

console.log(VariableWidth.value) // would be nice if it was 12
// right now it still prints 16
```

Comment: Thanks that's not a bad approach, I'll have to take a look and see if it will be time effective!