# It is possible to make a variable call a function every time it appears?

Tags: javascript

> Notice: This question is different from existing question [Javascript make variable a function that calls itself every time it's referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417792/javascript-make-variable-a-function-that-calls-itself-every-time-its-referenced)

I know it's possible to make a global variable a getter function.

Each time it gets called, the getter function will trigger.

```js
function bar() {
  console.log('test');
  return 42;
}

Object.defineProperty(window, 'foo', {
  get: bar
});

foo;  // 'test'

let a = foo;  // 'test'

let b = foo + foo;  // 'test' twice
```

But is it possible to make a non-global variable behave like this?

Like it defined with `const` or `let`.

It must be a standalone variable, can't be a dot notation of an other object like `obj.foo`.

```js
function bar() {
  console.log('test');
  return 42;
}

const foo = ???;

foo;    // 'test'

let a = foo;    // 'test'

let b = foo + foo;  // 'test' twice
```

I tried `Symbol.toPrimitive`, `valueOf` and `toString` etc. but it doesn't work for all the occasions:

```js
function bar() {
  console.log('test');
  return 42;
}

const foo = {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive]: bar,
  toString: bar,
  valueOf: bar
};

foo;

let a = foo;

let b = foo + foo;  // 'test' twice
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If a variable is a standalone variable (declared with `const` / `let` / `var`), and is not on the top level, there's no way to have custom Javascript code run when the variable name is simply *referenced*.

Put another way, referencing a standalone variable name is *pure* - it cannot have any side effects by itself, unless other parts of the code do something to it (such as with your `+` example).

Answer (score 1):

No.

The reason the `window` approach works is because you are **not defining** a `variable` on window, but actually a property. And this in conjunction with how JS does variable resolution ends up with the described behaviour.

Probably the only way of achieving what you want to do is to have access to the current scope, and all the clojure scopes and so on, but this is not available.